# Using PyAutoGUI to locate an image on screen regardless of the color tone / brightness

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm looking for a simple way in Python (PyAutoGUI) to locate all the images of a certain type on the screen but here's the catch, each image has a different gradient / color tone and I don't want to take the screen shot of each and every image to locate them on screen.

Here's the region of the screen containing the images I am trying to get the coordinates of:

[image]

As you can see every square has a unique color (the contrast).

So I want to get the coordinate of every square making PyAutoGUI scan just one image. Is there any way I could make it ignore the difference in contrast of the images? Like making it black and white mode or something.

How the code works:

```
import pyautogui
coordinates = pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen("image.png") # Returns list of coordinates of all images matching image.png
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this is 2 years old but for any future humans that find this like me try the confidence argument.

```
import pyautogui
button7location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('calc7key.png', confidence=0.9)
button7location
Box(left=1416, top=562, width=50, height=41)
```

Source: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions

Answer (score 3):

I would try the following:

```
pyautogui.locateOnScreen("image.png", grayscale=True)
```

Which will ignore color values and simply compaire the contrast of values. This has the added benefit of comparing about 30% quicker but can lead to false positives.

Comment: Ahh Looking closer at the image it looks that both color and contrast is altered per cell. This means that each cell is unique in all distinguishing ways other than location. If you could provide more specifics about your goal there may be more I could say on work-arounds.

Comment: Yes, this most likely won't work because the greyscale colors will still be different and PyAutoGUI does pixel-perfect matching.